# php - stristr find exact string

Tags: php, string

I have the following string:

```
P90 | Ash Wood (Well-Worn)
```

I'm passing this through the following:

```
$item = str_replace("|","", $item);
$item = str_replace(" (","-",$item);
$item = str_replace(")","",$item);
$item = str_replace(" ","-",$item);
$item = str_replace("--","-",$item);
$item = str_replace("™","",$item);
$item = str_replace("★-","",$item);
$item = str_replace("★","",$item);
```

Which returns:

```
P90-ASH-WOOD-WELL-WORN
```

I'm now comparing this string against a file of strings to find a match:

```
$lines = file(public_path().'/csgoanalyst.txt');
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    // Check if the line contains the string we're looking for, and print if it does
    if (stristr($line, $item)) {  // case insensitive
         echo $line;
         break;
    }
}
```

The problem I have is the file contains the follownig:

```
http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/2018/SOUVENIR-P90-ASH-WOOD-WELL-WORN
http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/919/P90-ASH-WOOD-WELL-WORN
```

both lines contain matches therefor are both valid, however I'm looking for an exact match - in this case the second URL.

Comment: Is `if (stristr($line, '/' + $item))` applicable in this case? It's better to do this prepending once, of course.

Comment: Try using preg_match as `/(?<!\-)(P90\-ASH\-WOOD\-WELL\-WORN)\b/`

Comment: No as `$line = 'http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/2018/SOUVENIR-P90-ASH-WOOD-WELL-WORN'` and `$item = 'P90-ASH-WOOD-WELL-WORN'`

Comment: My response was @raina77ow, sorry.

Comment: @raina77ow shouldn't that be `'/' . $item`? :-)

Comment: Argh, but of course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using `preg_match` as

```
$lines = file(public_path().'/csgoanalyst.txt');
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    // Check if the line contains the string we're looking for, and print if it does
    if(preg_match('/(?<!\-)(P90\-ASH\-WOOD\-WELL\-WORN)\b/',$line)) {  // case insensitive
         echo $line;
         break;
    }
}
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://eval.in/416655)

Answer (score 0):

Add this small code

- exploding line with '/' into array.
- access last value of array with end().
- comparing this to item variable then printing if matched.

  ```
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
    // Check if the line contains the string we're looking for, and print    if it does
      if (stristr($line, $item)) {  // case insensitive
        $lineArr = explode('/', $line);
        if(end($lineArr) == $item)
        {
          echo $line;
          break;
        }
      }
   }
  ```

Comment: `print_r($lineArr);

Array ( [0] => http: [1] => [2] => csgo.steamanalyst.com [3] => id [4] => 2018 [5] => SOUVENIR-P90-ASH-WOOD-WELL-WORN )`

Comment: what are you trying to convey?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this ...

```
 <?php
        $item = "P90-ASH-WOOD-WELL-WORN";
        $lines = array(
            "http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/2018/SOUVENIR-P90-ASH-WOOD-WELL-WORN",
            "http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/919/P90-ASH-WOOD-WELL-WORN-TEST",
            "http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/919/P90-ASH-WOOD-TEST-WELL-WORN",
            "http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/919/P90-ASH-WOOD-WELL-WORN"
        );

        foreach ($lines as $line) {

            echo "checking: ".$line."<br/>";

        // Check if the line contains the string we're looking for ...
            if (stristr($line, $item)) {  // case insensitive
                $line_as_array = explode('/', $line);
                if (end($line_as_array) === $item) { // check two string are same
                    echo "matched: ".$line."<br/>";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
```

and found the result as ...

```
checking: http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/2018/SOUVENIR-P90-ASH-WOOD-WELL-WORN
checking: http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/919/P90-ASH-WOOD-WELL-WORN-TEST
checking: http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/919/P90-ASH-WOOD-TEST-WELL-WORN
checking: http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/919/P90-ASH-WOOD-WELL-WORN
matched: http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/919/P90-ASH-WOOD-WELL-WORN
```

seems working ...

Comment: This still uses `http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/2018/SOUVENIR-P90-ASH-WOOD-WELL-WORN` and not `http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/919/P90-ASH-WOOD-WELL-WORN`

Answer (score 0):

My answer is to use end to only grab the last part of the explode'd string and then preg_match it with ^ and $ to signify beginning and end of the string you want to match. So anything with something on the front or the end will not match. Only exact matches will work.

```
<?
$item = "P90-ASH-WOOD-WELL-WORN";
$list = array("http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/2018/SOUVENIR-P90-ASH-WOOD-WELL-WORN","http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/919/P90-ASH-WOOD-WELL-WORN");

foreach ($list as $line)
{
    if (preg_match("/^$item$/",end(explode("/",$line))))
    {
        echo $line;
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

the result:

```
http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/919/P90-ASH-WOOD-WELL-WORN
```